# Calculating a Big O

Tags: c, data-structures, big-o, binary-search-tree

I am trying to calculate the Big-O of this function which is mirroring the (data structure) Binary search tree. But I'm not sure if  calculated right or not. Can you please explain what the Big-O of it would be?

```
void mirror(NODE *root){
    if (root) {
        mirror(root->left);
        mirror(root->right);
        NODE *temp = root->left;
        root->left = root-> right;
        root->right  = temp;
    }
    return;
}
```

I think it is *O(n)* because the function will run *n* times recursively and it depends on how many elements we have in the tree.

Comment: Big O of what (real-world time complexity, number of memory indirections, memory of comparisons, space, power consumptoon? worst case, best case, average case, median case?), relative to what (number of nodes? Is this a binary tree or a path, if a tree, depth, width, average, median, extremum)? Where do you start? Randomize? always at one end? Always in the middle?

Comment: What do you think it is? You say you calculated it so may as well share it.

Comment: @AbdusselamHijaziKelani **what** about the mirror function? real-world time complexits? or number of indirections? Or number of multiplications? Or number of null comparisons? Or number of memory swaps? Or memory/space?

Comment: It's simply O(n), where n is the number of nodes in the original tree.

Comment: I think it is Big (n) because the function will run n time recursively and it depends on how many element do we have in the tree.

Comment: So, this is about **time** complexity, and you are asking about complexity along the **number of elements**. But if it's a tree, then it's *not* O(n), @Barmar is wrong here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The tree depth is O(log(n)), but making the mirror simply copies every node.

Comment: It's not O(log(n)) because you do don't do constant amount of work at each level.

Comment: @Barmar right, and swapping a NULL and non-null ptr is the same effort, true.

Answer (score 1):

All operations apart from the function calls are constant time operations:

```
void mirror(NODE *root) {
    if (root) {                    // O(1)
        mirror(root->left);
        mirror(root->right);
        NODE *temp = root->left;   // O(1)
        root->left = root-> right; // O(1)
        root->right = temp;        // O(1)
    }
    return;                        // O(1)
}
```

The recursive calls will visit all nodes exactly once (depth-first traversal), so if  represents the number of nodes in the tree, then this has a time complexity of O()